# Could i write an extension to open an editor to side in Vs code

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I would like to make a vs code extension for that so a user presses a key combination than a text editor will open to the side where he could enter lines of text then whenever the text changes I would receive events with the changed text. Could you suggest to me how to open the editor if is it possible?
Thank you for taking the time to read the question.
Hope you have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use showTextDocument and use ViewColumn.Beside to open the editor to the side of the currently active one:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window

You can listen for text doc changes with the onDidChangeTextDocument event:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace

Here's info on creating a command to open the preview window.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands